# jupyter cells act like python, not ipython. I have ipykernel 6.9.1 - any ideas how to get ipython working in jlab?

Tags: jupyter, ipython, read-eval-print-loop

I use ipython regularly and expect to use it within jupyter, but the features are not available.

I downloaded and installed the anaconda3 python/jupyter packages recently and am running them. My Macbook is running Mac OS Monterey 12.6

What I see when running ipython outside of jupyter: I can enter -
In [3]: b=2;b
Out[3]: 2

But Jupyter notebook or lab I have to use a print statement to show the value.
v = 13
v
print(v)
13

Also statement completion works fine in ipython, but not in jlab/jnb
In [5]: import (lxml)

I have deleted the ipykernel(6.9.1) and reinstalled it but nothing seems to fix this. I'm a relative newbie so forgive me if the answer is obvious.

Comment: Only the last line in the notebook cells will be in the REPL. So putting a variable on the last line will allow you to get back its value without `print()`.  The lines above the last line are more like Python in that you'd need a `print()` or `display()` there. Tab-completion will work with `import l` to give `lxml` as an option in JupyterLab. You can see it in action in your browser (ipykernel 6.6.0 now) by going [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements), clicking `launch binder`, & then starting a new notebook. Run `%pip install lxml` in the first cell in the temporary session.

Comment: To switch to classic notebook: You can go to 'Help' on the left side of the main `File` bar. From under 'Help' select > `Launch Classic Notebook`. How things should be working there will be normal. This should let you compare to your own installation to rule out anything weird in your local install(s).